# Installed Ubuntu 13.1 on Laptop beside Win7 - no option to boot into windows - have run boot-repair

Tags: boot, windows, boot-repair

As my title explains.

After running Boot repair, my log is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6784795/

I still get no option to boot into windows

I would appreciate if someone could run an expert eye over the log and advise what my problem is and suggest some reading I can do to rectify it.
My laptop boots successfully into Ubuntu but I do not get a menu with a boot option for Windows.

Comment: what was the output of `sudo os-prober`?'

Comment: Avinash, the output of os-prober is at line 351 and 352 of the Boot-Repair log.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check this link, I feel its best to have two separate hard drives one for windows one for Ubuntu to be on the safe side, you can always install Ubuntu on an external hard drive and connect it to your computer through USB and run it that way its what i do, haven't had this problem before, this might help
V
V

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

[This should do the trick, I checked it out and it has everything needed to fix it](http://supergrubdisk.org)

You will need either a blank compact disk or a blank USB stick to use it.

I think you have to fix the Grub menu